# Esper - Can we do pipelined fashion processing using esper?

Tags: apache-storm, complex-event-processing, esper

I want to do some event processing using Esper in a pipelined fashion. I need to check for multiple cases for every event. 
For instance, say, i want to run my incoming data against following cases. How would I do it? What is the best way of doing it?

**case 1** = "If the current level is 400% greater than the average of last 5 consecutive values then mark the event with Exception-1"
**case 2** = "If the current level value is null then mark as Exception-2"
**case 3** = "If case 2 and case 3 are not matched, then the data is marked as 'safe'" 
**Following is the rough representation of what I want to do**

> ```
>      if (case1) { 
>        mark with Exception 1 
>      }
>
>      if (case2) {
>        mark with Exception 2 
>      }
>
>      if (none of the above cases matches) {
>          mark as safe 
>      }
> ```

Comment: @goodie Can you please answer this point too--> "If the current level is 400% greater than the average of last 5 consecutive values then mark as 'Exception1', If it is null mark as 'Exception 2', otherwise mark as 'safe' " And moreover they should be partitioned by 'location_id' property of the Event. While computing average of 5 consecutive values for checking, it should consider only the consecutive values for that location_id, not other locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
on Event 
insert into OutputStream select 'Exception 1' as label, * where level_detected > 400
insert into OutputStream select 'Exception 2' as label, * where level_detected = null
insert into OutputStream select 'safe' as label, *
```

You didn't ask how to do the detection for "If the current level is 400% greater than the average of last 5 consecutive values" so this is not part of my answer.

[Esper docs for split stream](http://espertech.com/esper/release-5.4.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#split_overview)

Comment: Can you please answer this point too--> "If the current level is 400% greater than the average of last 5 consecutive values then mark as 'Exception1', If it is null mark as 'Exception 2', otherwise mark as 'safe' "
 
And moreover they should be partitioned by 'location_id' property of the Event. While computing average of 5 consecutive values for checking, it should consider only the consecutive values for that location_id, not other locations.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyways~